# Soul never dies as per Gita. So does the memory always remain with the soul or it gets wiped out when a person dies?

Tags: atma, gita

So as per most of the Hindu scriptures, a soul never dies with the death of the body. Now a lot of memory, karma, bonding, etc has been accumulated by the body and soul during the tenure as a living person.

Do all these things get wiped out from the soul when a person dies? What actually happens with all the memory and experiences that the soul has felt when part of the living body?

Comment: When you die you retrieve your memory of all of your past lives.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36475/what-actually-transfers-during-rebirth/36544#36544

Comment: Yes, soul exists in the domain of space while past lives existed in the domain of time, and space-time together is a non-spatial continuum. The experiences of past lives i.e. Karma already became a person's ambiance, traits and features, while past birth memories are redundant information, as in the end only present exists, neither past nor future while soul is independent of body. People-animals that you perceive as beings in a material body form are existing, because they are not Self-aware.

Answer (score 1):

The Bhagavad Gita throws some light on this question

> श्री भगवानुवाच

> बहूनि मे व्यतीतानि जन्मानि तव चार्जुन।
> **तान्यहं वेद सर्वाणि न त्वं वेत्थ** परन्तप।।4.5।।

Swami Gambhirananda's English translation -

> 4.5 The Blessed Lord said O Arjuna, many lives of Mine have passed, and so have yours. **I know them all, (but) you know not,** O scorcher of enemies!

Shankara's Sanskrit commentary and Swami Gambhirananda's English translation -

> ।।4.5।। बहूनि मे मम व्यतीतानि अतिक्रान्तानि जन्मानि तव च हे अर्जुन। तानि अहं वेद जाने सर्वाणि न त्वं वेत्थ न जानीषे धर्माधर्मादिप्रतिबद्धज्ञानशक्तित्वात्। अहं पुनः नित्यशुद्धबुद्धमुक्तस्वभावत्वात् अनावरणज्ञानशक्तिरिति वेद अहं हे परंतप।।

> 4.5 O Arjuna, bahuni, many; janmani, lives; me, of Mine; vyatitani, have passed; tava ca, and so have yours. Aham, I; veda know; tani, them; sarvani, all; (but) **tvam, you; va vetta, know not, due to your power of understanding being obstructed by righteousness, unrighteousness, etc. However, parantapa, O scorcher of foes; aham, I know, possessing as I do unobstructed power of knowledge, because by nature I am eternal, pure, enlightened and free.**

Thus, assuming we are all similar to Arjuna, we do not remember our past lives due to obstruction in our understanding, where as the Lord knows everything as He/She is enlightened and free. The implication is that memories of experiences of past lives are hidden/obscured, rather than completely wiped out.