# What exactly reaches the chidakasam?

Tags: yoga, saraswati, yoga-vashishtha

An yogi with proper practice can reach chidakasam, which is generally treated as Samadi state. The chidakasam (space of intelligence) is beyond chittakasam (space of mind) and stulakasam (space of sensible/physical world). This can be understood from the following words of Saraswathi to Lila

> "His spirit is now roving in the sky, of which there are **three
> kinds:—one the firmament or region of the sensible worlds; the other
> is the region of the mind, the seat of volition and creation; and
> third is the region of Intellect, which contains the two others.** Your
> husband's soul is now in the sheath of the region of Intellect; (being
> withdrawn both from the regions of the visible world and sensuous
> mind). It is now by seeking in the region of the Intellect, that
> things which are in existent here, are to be found there. **As in
> passing from one place to another, you are conscious of standing in
> the mid spot, (which is neither the one nor the other); so you will
> arrive in an instant at the intermediate region of the intellectual
> world, (lying between this sensible and spiritual worlds). If you will
> abide in that intellectual world, after forsaking all your mental
> desires, you will certainly come to the knowledge of that spiritual
> Being who comprehends all in himself**.It is only by your knowledge of
> the negative existence of the world, that you can come to know the
> positive existence of that Being, as you will now be able to do by my
> grace, and by no other means whatever."
>
> [[10-14, Chapter 17 - Story of the doubtful realm or reverie of lila, Utpatti khanda, Yoga Vasistha]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118071.html)

Saraswathi says that one can go to chidakasam by the aforementioned procedure. But, what is the exact entity of the yogi that reaches the chidakasam.

Is it [sushma sareera (subtle body) as in the case of rebith](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36537/661)? Or is it any other entity of yogi that reaches chidakasam?