# Did the Samkhya school believe that destroying plants in Yagnas is a sin?

Tags: philosophy, practice, vedanta, plants, sankhya

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3193/36), by far the most popular school of Hindu philosophy is the Vedanta school. But there are five other Astika or orthodox schools of Hindu philosophy: Purva Mimamsa, Samkhya, Yoga, Vaisheshika, and Nyaya.  My question is about the Samkhya school, founded by the sage Kapila.  Verse 2 of Ishwara Krishna's Samkhya Karika, the defining text of the Samkhya school, describes the flaws of pursuing happiness through Dharma, and advocates pursuing happiness through knowledge of Purusha and Prakriti instead:

> dṛṣṭavadānuśravikaḥ sa hyaviśuddhi kṣayātiśayayuktaḥ । 
>   tadviparītaḥ śreyān vyaktāvyaktajñavijñānāt ॥
>
> The [means of happiness revealed by the Vedas] is like the evident one, It is linked with **impurity**, destruction and inequality. Other than that is better,—proceeding from the right cognition of the Manifest, Unmanifest and the Knower.

Now I had assumed the word "impurity" referred to the Samkhya school's belief that animal sacrifice in Vedic Yagnas is a sin, albeit an easily remedied one as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19626/36).  (This is in contrast to the Vedanta school which supports animal sacrifice, as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7947/36).) And indeed, that's exactly the sort of explanation given by the Samkhya Karika Bhashya, attributed to the Advaita philosopher Gaudapada:

> Linked with impurity, because of the slaughter of animals. As it is said: “According to the injunction in the aśvamedha, six hundred animals, minus three, are employed (i.e., slaughtered) at midday.”

But [this excerpt](http://preview.ibb.co/bVaaaQ/image.jpg) from the Tattva Kaumudi, a commentary on the Samkhya Karika by the Advaita philosopher Vachaspati Mishra, suggests that the supposed impurity of Vedic Yagnas is not limited to animal sacrifice:

> [The means of happiness revealed by the Vedas] is "impure" because sacrifices like soma yagna, etc. are performed by the sacrifice of animals and **destruction of corn**, etc.

I'm interested in the part in bold.  My question is, did the Samkhya school believe that the destruction of plants like corn in Vedic Yagnas is a sin?  Or is this just a belief of Vachaspati Mishra, given that he was an Advaitin and not an actual follower of the Samkhya school?

I've never heard a Hindu criticize the destroying of plants in Yagnas before.  I've only heard Charvakas and other non-Hindus criticizing wasting food in Yagnas.  But are there any Samkhya works which discuss this issue?